# How do I change the locale/layout of software input panel (SIP) in WinCE 6 r3

Tags: visual-c++, keyboard, windows-ce, registry, soft-keyboard

### Dear fellow Windows CE developers,

in my current project i need support for German keyboard layout on my Windows CE device. Setting the locale accordingly the **software keyboard input** driver still doesn't offer a **QWERTZ layout**.

since the system is correctly localized i think the necessary files are available in a standard VS 2005 with Windows CE 6 r3 sources.

***How do I change the locale/layout of software input panel (SIP) in WinCE 6 r3?***

- Does it have something to do with the [physical keyboard registry settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee484252%28v=WinEmbedded.60%29.aspx)?
- Do i need to create the layout by myself with the [LayoutGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504599%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx)?
- Do i need to add the German Transcriber or any other component in the catalog items list?

i'd appreciate answers about this detail, that already ate up quite some time for me!
have a nice day!

*relevant registry keys:*

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{42429667-ae04-11d0-a4f8-00aa00a749b9}\IsSIPInputMethod]
@="1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{42429667-ae04-11d0-a4f8-00aa00a749b9}\InputLanguage]
"0407"=dword:00000001
"0409"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{42429667-ae04-11d0-a4f8-00aa00a749b9}\DefaultLanguage]
@="0407"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\SIP]
"DefaultIm"="{42429667-ae04-11d0-a4f8-00aa00a749b9}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Drivers\BuiltIn\SIP]
"Locale"="0407"
"Keyboard Layout"="00000407"

[HEKY_LOCAL_MACHINE\MUI]
"Enable"=dword:00000001
"SysLang"=dword:00000407
"CurLang"=dword:00000407
```

i came also across setting up a new layout key. however i don't know, if the correct layout is implicitly compiled to the kbdmouse.dll (which is the standard for US layout).

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Layouts\00000407]
"Layout File"="kdbmouse.dll"
"Layout Text"="My QWERTZ Keyboard"
"KPPLayout"="kdbmouse.dll"          ;no clue what this key defines :(
```